# Subclassing UIButton to handle clicks

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am trying to subclass the UIButton to create a "smarter" button that contains logic for handling the click event.

What is the best way to achieve this? Do I simply need to override an onClick method? Or do I need to register an event handler (and if so, where should this be done seeing as there are many ways to init a UIButton?)

Comment: What to you mean by 'click event'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bsubclass+%2Buibutton&submit=search

Comment: @dandan78 I want my button to perform some action when it is clicked. I want this logic to be contained inside my button. To provide a bit more detail, I am creating an app where each button plays a sound - so I want each of my button to also encapsulate an instance of AVAudioPlayer, which should play when the button is clicked.

Comment: you are about the violate the [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)-Pattern. A button is a view. as such it displays information and might handle user input. it should handle no other task.

Comment: I realize that. However, I think for my current application it would simplify things A LOT. Think about an app that has 100 buttons, each with it's own sound and behaviour. The two options I see are either build the sound/behavior into the button and have it contain itself. OR, maintain a mapping that requires logic to figure out which button was clicked, and what it's behavior should do.

Comment: "Think about an app that has 100 buttons, each with it's own sound and behaviour." - The last thing you want then is 100 AVAudioPlayers then. Create one. Pass the sound file in on the button press.

Comment: @Velox that's actually not possible (see apple Docs). The file is loaded on construction of the AVAudioPlayer object and there is no method exposed to update the file. Further, my sounds need to be played simultaneously (thus the need for multiple AVAudioPlayer instances).

Comment: Have one instance variable for the AVAudioPlayer. On every button touch initialize it, play the audio and release it.

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted so much and I also don't think subclassing a button to play a sound when it's touched would "violate" the MVC pattern. Input feedback, whether it's visible or audible (think about VoiceOver for example) can clearly be a part of the view.

Comment: vikingosegundo, Josh Caswell, Mehul, Janak Nirmal, David Rönnqvist 
This is a great question!! The asker is requesting the "best" method for solving a problem.  Responses might include references to Apple documentation or other helpful discussion.

Comment: This does not in the slightest violate MVC, has no connection in any way, at all, to MVC issues, and is the utterly normal and completely standard, correct, practice.

Comment: It's profoundly bizarre that this question was closed!  (Note that, indeed, it's such a normal and common iOS issue that the question has indeed ... been asked and answered a number of times on the site!!   Eg, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51158513/294884  )  Totally bizarro!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think there are better solutions to this problem than what you've proposed, but to answer your question directly: A subclass of UIButton observes touch events the same way that everyone else observes touch events.

```
// In your UIButton subclass

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    if (self) {
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(didTouchButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didTouchButton {
    // do whatever you need to do here
}
```

Important note: you can't use `[UIButton buttonWithType:]` to create your button, you've got to use `init` or `initWithFrame:`. Even though UIButton has the convenience initializer, `initWithFrame:` is still the designated initializer.

Comment: For 2020, here's the everyday Swift solution to this common problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51158513/294884