# Custom UIButton class for button touch event

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiviewanimation

Is it possible to create a custom UIButton class with an touch event animation which gets automatically invoked everytime the user touches the button?

```
 import UIKit

 class AnimatedButton: UIButton {

     @objc private func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

              UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                             delay: 1.0,
                             usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0,
                             initialSpringVelocity: 0.2,
                             options:  .curveEaseOut,
                             animations: {
                                 //do animation
                                 sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
                             },
                             completion: nil)

     }
  }
```

So I don't want to create an action in a ViewController in which button.buttonTouched() must be invoked. This should happen automatically everytime I use this class in all UIButton.

Is there any possibility to do something like that?

Comment: @mr-tann : Take a look at the answer posted below, lemme know if it works

Answer (score 6):

Create the button's custom class  like this

```
class CustomButton:UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configeBtn()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configeBtn()
    }

    func configeBtn() {

        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func btnClicked (_ sender:UIButton) {

        // animate here 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Though subclassing `UIButton` is not something that I would prefer, the animating action that you wanna achieve for your button with subclassing `UIButton` can be achieved by overriding `sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?)`

As per comments in `UIControl` class (`UIButton` inherits from `UIControl`)

> send the action. the first method is called for the event and is a
>   point at which you can observe or override behavior

```
class MyButton : UIButton {
    override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {
        debugPrint("Am here")
        //do all your animation stuff here
        super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
    }
}
```

So whenever button is tapped your animation will be executed and then `IBAction` will be invoked. Hope this helps

Comment: this also needs a target added to be triggered

Comment: @sh-khan : Question is not about how to avoid adding target, rather idea is to invoke animation when user touches the button without actually explicitly triggering the buttonClicked method in each action / target

Comment: yes, but also this needs to link the button to a dummy empty IBAction